# How to build a keyword so I don't have to run login to all the features of a web in a test case of robot framework using seleniumlibrary?

Tags: selenium, authentication, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I wanna test the features about the website in my final project in my Subject about Testing. I literally beginner in this field and confused how to create keyword in robot framework so I don't have to include the login part to all the features that I am going to test.

As you can see in my sample code that in every single feature that I am going to test I have to start from login part first. Actually, there are 10 features that I am going to test off.

What I need to implement is I don't have to always login to each feature which means it reduces the process so I can jump to the features that I am going to test. I mean I have login function that handle to all the features.

Forgive me if my question is about confusing at all. 
I provide these sample codes below to make you understand about my question

```
*** Settings ***

 Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

 LoginTest

Open Browser    *website-url*    chrome
Set Selenium Implicit Wait    5
Sleep    2
Click Element    //*[@id="headertop"]/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a
Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input    username
Input Password    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input   password
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="sidebar-wp-submit"] 
Sleep    3

Log    Task Completed
```

ViewProfileTest

```
Open Browser    *website-url*    chrome
Set Selenium Implicit Wait    5
Sleep    2
Click Element    //*[@id="headertop"]/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a
Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input    username
Input Password    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input   password
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="sidebar-wp-submit"] 
Sleep    3
Click Element    //*[@id="headertop"]/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a
Sleep    1
Click Element    //*[@id="sidebar-me"]/ul[1]/li[3]/a
```

ViewHistoryTest

```
Open Browser    *website-url    chrome
Set Selenium Implicit Wait    5
Sleep    2
Click Element    //*[@id="headertop"]/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a
Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input    username
Input Password    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input   password    
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="sidebar-wp-submit"] 
Sleep    3
Click Element    //*[@id="headertop"]/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a
Sleep    1
Click Element    //*[@id="sidebar-me"]/ul[1]/li[3]/a
Sleep    1
Click Element    //*[@id="user-mycred-history"]
```

What I want to Achieve: Login Once that test all the features without login in every feature

Comment: 1. StackOverflow is not for making your homework, bur because you are asking for a specific thing I think we will make an exception
2. I am not sure, what o you mean by "keyword", because I didn't work  with it. I recommend to read documentation for the framework + good luck in solving it :) , wish ya good luck

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion mate, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The is one of the ways you can approach the issue,

step 1 :- create [____init____.robot](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id555)
Keep all the common functions in this file for example Login Keyword in this case, and, now, all the tests would call this function  by making use of   **Test Setup** in their respective testcase files.

```
*** Keywords ***
LoginTest

Open Browser    *website-url*    chrome
Set Selenium Implicit Wait    5
Sleep    2
Click Element    //*[@id="headertop"]/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a
Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input    username
Input Password    xpath=//*[@id="login_register_form"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input   password
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="sidebar-wp-submit"] 
Sleep    3

Log    Task Completed
```

Here, in both step 2 and step 3, login and logout keywords which are created only once in ____init____.robot file would be called every time, by the respective testcases created under each file which contains Test Setup LoginTest.
Notice that in yout testcase file, nowhere you have repeated the same login code, instead, you are making use of Test Setup to call Login feature for every testcase.

step 2:- ViewProfileTest

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup       LoginTest
Test Teardown    LogoutTest

*** Test Cases ***
TestFeature#1
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown from setting table
    Do Something
```

step 3:- ViewHistoryTest

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup       LoginTest
Test Teardown    LogoutTest

*** Test Cases ***
TestFeature#1
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown from setting table
    Do Something
```